# JTextArea append() method writes twice?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jtextarea

I've run into a little problem.
In my GUI, I have a text area in the center (`BorderLayout`). Then I have a `JList` on the West.

When I click on a member of the song titles I have in my list, the text area should display the title, artist, and price of the song. 
I have everything working, but the problem is that when I click on a member, the title,artist, and the price is displayed TWICE.

Here is the code for "valueChanged()" and parts of codes relevant.

```
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
      {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        int index = songList.getSelectedIndex();
        Song selection = songCollection[index];

        if(source == songList)
        {
            textArea.append(selection.getTitle() + "    " + selection.getArtist() + "   " + selection.getPrice() + "\n" );
        }
      }
    private Song songCollection[] = new Song[5];
    private String songTitle[] = new String[5];

    //Fill song array
    songCollection = getSongs();
    songTitle = getSongTitle();

    //Methods:
     public Song[] getSongs()
    {
    Song[] array = new Song[5];
    array[0] = new Song("Summer", "Mozart", 1.50);
    array[1] = new Song("Winter", "Mozart", 1.25);
    array[2] = new Song("Spring", "Mozart", 2.00);
    array[3] = new Song("Baby", "Justin Bieber", 0.50);
    array[4] = new Song("Firework", "Katy Perry", 1.00);

    return array;
     }

public String[] getSongTitle()
{
    String[] names = new String[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        names[i] = songCollection[i].getTitle();

    return names;
}
```

I noticed something just now when I was fiddling around with my program again. When I press a member in the list, it is still printed TWICE like before. However, I noticed that it prints once when I press and hold down my mouse, and it prints AGAIN when I let go of it. So if I press my mouse on 1 member, and drag the cursor up/down to other members, they print once, but when I let go of the mouse, it prints the one I ended in one more time.

Comment: Please don't use tags in the title.

Comment: do you want to show maximum of 1 song at a time or it can be more.?

Comment: It should be more than 1 song at a time (text area is supposed to be a shopping cart). That's why I used append() and not setText()

Answer (score 3):

`JTextArea.append()` is being called twice from your `ListSelectionListener`.

The reason can be found in ***[How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)***:

> Many list selection events can be generated from a single user action such as a mouse click. The getValueIsAdjusting method returns true if the user is still manipulating the selection. This particular program is interested only in the final result of the user's action, so the valueChanged method does something only if getValueIsAdjusting returns false.

You need to check that the selection in the `JList` is no longer being manipulated. You can surround the `append` method with the check:

```
if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
   textArea.append(...);
}
```

Comment: `if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false)` should be simply written `if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting())`

Comment: Yes, this worked (though I'd figured it out a little before you told me :D)
Thank you anyways!